# scrolling effect only takes effect on the last item of array of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm trying to achieve so far in the portfolio site that I'm creating is the dynamic marking of an active nav item depending on the section the user is scrolling on. For example, if the user is on the "Works" section, Javascript will apply the .active-nav-item class name to the "Works" nav item that has an href of #works since the id of the "Works" section is works.

`<a href="#works">` for `<section id="works">`
`<a href="#design">` for `<section id="design">`
`<a href="#story">` for `<section id="story">`
`<a href="#contact">` for `<section id="contact">`

It's like the nav menu is telling the user what section he/she is currently on.
The problem is: when I scroll down, only the last item, which is the Contact, takes effect; the other three show nothing.

```js
var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

var elems = ['works', 'design', 'story', 'contact'];

elems.forEach(function(elem) {
  window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentElem = this;
    if (currentElem.pageYOffset >= query(`#${elem}`).offsetTop) {
      query(`.banner-header > nav > a[href='#${elem}']`).classList.add('active-nav-item');
    } else {
      query(`.banner-header > nav > a[href='#${elem}']`).classList.remove('active-nav-item');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<section id="banner">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header class="banner-header">
      <a href="" class="logo">MyLogo</a>
      <nav>
        <a href="#works">Works</a>
        <a href="#design">Design</a>
        <a href="#story">Story</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="banner-body flex">
      <div class="centered">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a href="" class="primary">Get Started</a>
          <a href="" class="secondary">See on GitHub</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="banner-footer">
      <a href=""><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section id="works" style="width:100%; min-height:100vh">
  <h3>Works</h3>
</section>

<section id="design" style="width:100%; min-height:100vh">
  <h3>Design</h3>
</section>

<section id="story" style="width:100%; min-height:100vh">
  <h3>Story</h3>
</section>

<section id="contact" style="width:100%; min-height:100vh">
  <h3>Contact</h3>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because `window.onscrol`l can be binded to only one function you are trying to bind one for each element so it gets binded to for last element only as it was last element for which `onscroll` function was being binded!

That's not how its done. You need to do the loop inside the `onscroll` function not the reverse of this!

Also one more problem with your code is that you need to remove `active` class from each `a` before adding onto other.

This is how it will be done :

```
<script>
            var query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

            var elems = ['works', 'design', 'story', 'contact'];

            window.onscroll = function() {              
                elems.forEach(function(elem) {
                    if(window.pageYOffset >= query(`#${elem}`).offsetTop) {
                        // removing active class first 
                        var li = document.querySelectorAll('.banner-header > nav > a');
                        for(var i = 0; i < li.length; i++)li[i].classList.remove('active-nav-item');

                        //now adding class to specific `a`
                        query(`.banner-header > nav > a[href='#${elem}']`).classList.add('active-nav-item');
                    } else {
                        query(`.banner-header > nav > a[href='#${elem}']`).classList.remove('active-nav-item');
                    }
                });
            };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, buddy :)